# How do I close ports on the Mac OS X firewall?

Tags: macos, mac, firewall

Using 10.6.8

I turned on my firewall and clicked block all incoming connections.  But for some reason I can  still browse to my webserver.  How do I turn off those, port (80), or the application (apache) running it?

Thank you.

Comment: The port's probably closed only to external connections. Try hitting that service from another machine on your network. I wager the port is closed.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off apache, go to system preferences then sharing and make sure that web sharing is not selected. That's it.

Comment: In 10.8 this is no longer an option.